# HtmlUnit - code works on my own system, not on my VPS?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have written some code to automate a certain task I want to perform and it works fine on my computer. Since this task has to be executed every hour, I am running it on my VPS (Amazon).
But running the code on my VPS gives me most of the times errors that I can't reproduce on my own computer. On my own computer I can run it as many time as I want and every time it works correctly.

Can anyone think of a possible reason why this is happening?

My code is:

```
public final class Test {

    // XPath elements
    private static final String USERNAME_FIELD = "//*[@id=\"username\"]";
    private static final String PASSWORD_FIELD = "//*[@id=\"password\"]";
    private static final String SIGN_IN_BUTTON = "//*[@id=\"loginForm\"]/fieldset[2]/button";
    private static final String RUN_TEST_BUTTON = "/html/body/div[1]/div/header/div/div/button/span";

    // User credentials
    private static final String USERNAME = "my-username";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "my-password";

    // TestObject URL's
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "url";
    private static final String RUN_TEST_URL = "my-test-url;

    private static final int TIME_OUT = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

        try (final WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
            client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
            client.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());

            client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
            client.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
            client.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(false);
            client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            client.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(true);
            client.getOptions().setTimeout(TIME_OUT);
            client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            client.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(true);
            //client.setHTMLParserListener(HTMLParserListener.LOG_REPORTER);
            client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(TIME_OUT/2);

            HtmlPage page = client.getPage(LOGIN_URL);
            HtmlTextInput user = (HtmlTextInput) page.getByXPath(USERNAME_FIELD).get(0);
            HtmlPasswordInput pass = (HtmlPasswordInput) page.getByXPath(PASSWORD_FIELD).get(0);
            HtmlButton login = (HtmlButton) page.getByXPath(SIGN_IN_BUTTON).get(0);

            user.setValueAttribute(USERNAME);
            pass.setValueAttribute(PASSWORD);

            page = login.click();

            page = client.getPage(RUN_TEST_URL);
            HtmlSpan runTest = (HtmlSpan) page.getByXPath(RUN_TEST_BUTTON).get(0); // this is the place where it gives an "out-of-bound exception"

            page = runTest.click();

            client.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Undefined@2c543bc‌​5 
>       Exception in thread "main" 
>       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 
>           at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653) 
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429) 
>           at eu.theappfactory.testobject.driver.TestObjectDriver.main(Tes‌​tObjectDriver.java:7‌​1)

Comment: Can you post the error Message?

Comment: Yes. The error message looks like this:      net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Undefined@2c543bc5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at eu.theappfactory.testobject.driver.TestObjectDriver.main(TestObjectDriver.java:71) - (above it you see some url encoded data; but it's too long to fit here (it's much higher than the allowed characters)

Comment: I have figured it out. The website I am automating is from Germany, and my Amazon instance is from Frankfurt. And I myself am from The Netherlands. So they show different content to German users and that's why my HTML doesn't match.

Comment: It might be a useful test that content is different based on location